# Qt modifying a JSON file

Tags: c++, json, qt

I need to be able to read in an existing JSON file, make modifications to it (such as replacing, removing and adding objects, arrays and key-value pairs), and then write the file out again.

I have am trying to read and write to a JSON file with these contents:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "name": "Channel",
            "default": 1

        },
        {
            "name": "Size",
            "default": 457
        }
    ]
}
```

I am reading the file in successfully, but failing to make any changes to it using the following code:

```
QFile File("/path/to/myfile.json");
File.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);

QJsonParseError JsonParseError;
QJsonDocument JsonDocument = QJsonDocument::fromJson(File.readAll(), &JsonParseError);

File.close();

QJsonObject RootObject = JsonDocument.object();
QJsonArray Array = RootObject.value("array").toArray();

QJsonObject ElementOneObject = Array.at(0).toObject();

ElementOneObject.insert("key", QJsonValue(QString("value")));
ElementOneObject.insert("name", QJsonValue(QString("David")));

File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Truncate);
File.write(JsonDocument.toJson());
File.close();
```

I am expecting to see the first element of the array to have a new name of "David" and a new key-value pair like `"key" : "value"`. The contents of the file are identical after this code has run. I know the file has been written out, because the ordering of the key-value pairs has been changed to be ordered by the keys sorted into alphabetic order.

How do I get the file to refelct the changes I have tried to make?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason the example in the question does not work is because `JsonDocument.object()`, `RootObject.value("array").toArray()` and `Array.at(0).toObject()` all return copies of the data, not references. There are two different ways to handle this.

1) After making you changes to the element, insert it into the copy of your array, then insert the array into the `RootObject` copy, then set the `RootObject` on the `JsonDocument`

```
Array.removeAt(0);
Array.insert(0, ElementOneObject);
RootObject.insert("array", Array);
JsonDocument.setObject(RootObject);
```

2) Use `find()` to get references to the objects/values you want to modify

```
QJsonObject RootObject = JsonDocument.object();
QJsonValueRef ArrayRef = RootObject.find("array").value();
QJsonArray Array = ArrayRef.toArray();

QJsonArray::iterator ArrayIterator = Array.begin();
QJsonValueRef ElementOneValueRef = ArrayIterator[0];

QJsonObject ElementOneObject = ElementOneValueRef.toObject();

// Make modifications to ElementOneObject

ElementOneValueRef = ElementOneObject;
ArrayRef = Array;
JsonDocument.setObject(RootObject);
```

Comment: How do I find an object with given key:value pair, then modify the another key:value on the same object?

Answer (score 2):

You create the Json document from the file, then get the first (root) item, RootObject. This is not a reference to the root item in the JsonDocument, but a copy.

Therefore, create a new JsonDocument from the modified root item and save that.

```
QJsonDocument doc(RootObject);

File.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text | QFile::Truncate);
File.write(doc.toJson());
File.close();
```

Alternatively, there's this function that may just set the root object back into the QJsonDocument that you first created: -

```
void QJsonDocument::setObject(const QJsonObject & object)
```

So before saving, try calling

```
JsonDocument.setObject(RootObject);
```

Comment: I had tried setObject() before, but it wasn't enough. I think the problem is that RootObject is a copy, then you get the Array, which is also a copy, and then you get an element out of that array, which is also a copy! I have it working if I do this at the end:
Array.takeAt(0);
Array.insert(0, ElementOneObject);
RootObject.insert("array", Array);
JsonDocument.setObject(RootObject);

This seems a bit insane though!

Comment: Once you get the root object, if you use the find function, it returns an iterator to the actual data for the key. This should allow you to change the data directly, before calling setObject at the end.