# writing to previously existing json file(with array of objects and each object with an array member) using qt 5.3

Tags: json, qt

I am using QT 5.3. I have read various materials present online describing how to write json file,but no content describes it systematically and stepwise.

It would be really helpful if someone can explain the stepwise process of writing a json file in simple language since i am new to qt.

In my case i have a json file that already exists "LOM.json" with some content.How do i add new data to this.
`{
  "LOM": [
    {
      "LOM ID": 1,
      "Source": "Open Internet",
      "Content": "Complete Reference Java.pdf",
      "Difficulty Level": "Hard",
      "Type": "Text",
      "Length": "Long",
      "Topic-Proficiency": [
        {
          "Topic": "Programming",
          "Proficiency": "E2"
        },
        {
          "Topic": "Java",
          "Proficiency": "E3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "LOM ID": 2,
      "Source": "Open Internet",
      "Content": "www.LatexTutorial.com",
      "Difficulty Level": "Medium",
      "Type": "WebCourse",
      "Length": "Medium",
      "Topic-Proficiency": [
        {
          "Topic": "Latex",
          "Proficiency": "E2"
        }
      ]
    }
]
}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it done.
Actually the mistake was that while declaring the QJsonObject and QjsonArray,i was declaring them as pointer type that's why it was not allowing to insert qjsonobject to qjsonarray.
As far as writing to already existing json file is concerned,firstly the file is to be opened and content is to be read in qjsonarray or object.Next the changes to be done are appended to the read data(in qjson object or qjsonarray) and finally the new value is inserted to the read document by removing the previous one.
Thanks @merlin069 and this post -[Qt modifying a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19267335/qt-modifying-a-json-file).

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly insert data into the middle of the document. You would need to read the document and write it out again. Let's look at how we'd go about this.

Assuming the current JSON you posted is in memory as a QByteArray, you create a QJsonDocument:-

```
QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(data); // where data is the current JSON
```

If we want to add another LOM object to the array. We get the first object, which is the array:-

```
QJsonObject rootObj = doc.object();
QJsonValue lomObj = rootObj.value("LOM");

if(!lomObj.isArray())
{
    // array expected - handle error
}

QJsonArray lomArray = lomObj.toArray();
```

Now we have the array, we can create a new object

```
QJsonObj newObject;
newObject["LOM ID"] = 3;
newObject["Source"] = "Open Internet"
newObject["Content"] = "Some other content"
//etc...
```

And add this to the array

```
lomArray.push_back(newObject);
```

Finally, you can create a new document and get a byte array of the data to write to the file

```
QJsonDocument newDoc(obj);
QByteArray finalData = newDoc.toJson();
```

Comment: Yes that is what i am doing..first read the existing document and then added new object to the array and then rewrite it. But the problem is when i try to insert an object in an array..it is not allowed since entries in QJsonArray should be of type QJsonValue.For example-for each object there is a key value pair "Topic-Proficiency" which is an array of objects itself,so when i try to add QJsonObject to this array it is not allowed.

Comment: //QDomDocument newDoc(obj);//

Not QDomDocument. Should be QJsonDocument.

Comment: @HareenLaks, thanks - was working on XML when doing that! I've corrected the answer.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, :) But I also have issue with your solution. Even I create a new QJsonDocument old content still on the file. 

Note that I open the file like below. Is it reason for that?
`json_records_file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)`

Comment: @HareenLaks, without seeing your code, it's difficult to know what the problem is. I suggest starting a new question on SO. If you link to it here, I'll take a look.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, Thanks for helping me. I created a question on below link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074882/writing-to-the-existing-json-file-not-overwrite-old-contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074882/writing-to-the-existing-json-file-not-overwrite-old-contents)