# Writing to the existing JSON file not overwrite old contents

Tags: json, qt

I'm going to overwrite a existing JSON file using c++/Qt. I searched lot and interested to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179907/2206240) which appear as answer for my question.

I was able to write to the JSON file using that. But the issue is existing content still at the file.

This is my code.

```qt
void ServerRecordCreator::writeToLocal(Record *record) const
{
    QFile json_records_file(QDir::currentPath() + "/WrittenRecords.json");
    if (json_records_file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
    {
        QJsonParseError error;
        QJsonDocument json_records_document(QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_records_file.readAll(),&error));
        if(!json_records_document.isNull()){
            QJsonObject json_root_object;
            d->writeRecord(record,json_root_object,json_records_document);
            QJsonDocument new_document(json_root_object);
            json_records_file.write(new_document.toJson());
        }else
        {
            qDebug() << error.errorString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("Cannot found or open the WrittenRecords.json file %s:%d", __FILE__ , __LINE__);
        return;
    }
}
```

```qt
 void writeRecord(Record *record, QJsonObject &json_root_object,QJsonDocument &json_document) const
    {
        bool record_found = false;
        QJsonObject json_record_object;
        record->write(json_record_object);

        if(!json_document.isNull()){
            QJsonObject::iterator i;
            for(i= json_document.object().begin();i !=json_document.object().end();i++)
            {
                QVariant key = i.key();
                if(record->type() == record->stringToRecordType(key.toString()))
                {
                    QJsonValue records =json_document.object().value(i.key());
                    QJsonArray records_array = records.toArray();
                    records_array.push_back(json_record_object);
                    json_root_object[record->recordTypeToString(record->type())] = records_array;
                    record_found = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!record_found)
        {
            json_root_object[record->recordTypeToString(record->type())] = json_record_object;
        }
    }
```

WrittenRecords.json file before written.

```json
{
    "ATHLETE_RECORD": [
        {
            "club": "BCsC",
            "date_of_birth": "Mon Jan 5 2015",
            "first_name": "Lakshan",
            "id_gender": 2,
            "last_name": "Perera"
        }
    ]
}
```

After that

```json
{
    "ATHLETE_RECORD": [
        {
            "club": "BCsC",
            "date_of_birth": "Mon Jan 5 2015",
            "first_name": "Lakshan",
            "id_gender": 2,
            "last_name": "Perera"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "ATHLETE_RECORD": [
        {
            "club": "BCsC",
            "date_of_birth": "Mon Jan 5 2015",
            "first_name": "Lakshan",
            "id_gender": 2,
            "last_name": "Perera"
        },
        {
            "club": "NdCC",
            "date_of_birth": "Mon Jan 5 2015",
            "first_name": "Lakshan",
            "id_gender": 2,
            "last_name": "Perera"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you code looks fine to me , have you tried deleting the original file and creating and writing to the new one ? try opening the file with `QIODevice::Truncate` after reading it.

Comment: After you read in the original file, are you closing it and reopening it? If you're not closing it, then you need to seek to the beginning of the file before writing, using QFile::seek(0);

Comment: @AlirezaSoori, Not tried. I tried to use `QIODevice::Truncate` add the time of opening. But it deletes all from the file before reading it. I found that it is a way of truncate works. So I'm going to open the file two times, first time for read, then for write with the truncate. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, yes. I'm not closing it. And `QFile::seek(0);` worked for me. But now I'm going to open the file twice as mentioned in the previous comment. Thank you very much for the support.